# How can I make a lot of gil?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

What is the fastest way to make gil? Is there some trick to repeatedly gain lots of gil?

I am more concerned on a high level, what's the trick to get a lot of gil? Is there some way to repeat something and get a lot of gil every time?

Comment: What part of the game you are at would be help, Gil farming in this game is basically just what monsters you should be killing to sell the items :)

Comment: @Josh: I'm just starting. It would be nice to know places I can go to get gil at "any" level. So if you could provide me info on certain ranges of levels it would be nice. But I'm more concerned for a higher level, the best way to make a lot of gil in general. Is there some trick? Like getting a high reward everytime or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Where should I go to farm Gil quickly in Final Fantasy 13?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/628/where-should-i-go-to-farm-gil-quickly-in-final-fantasy-13)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [gil farming guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/928790-final-fantasy-xiii/faqs/59442) at gamefaqs, but it deals with near endgame, endgame, and postgame farming.  In the beginning of the game there's not really much you can do to farm gil other than selling components.  Most components sell for a pittance relative to the cost of anything you might actually want to buy, so it's generally more worth it to use them to upgrade your accessories (heavily upgraded +str or +magic accessories can really make the early game easy.)  There's also not much to buy anyway.  PSICOM or Guardian Corps enemies have a chance to drop a Credit Chip, which sells for 500 gil, and has no other purpose.  There's a few encounters in the early game that I think always drop them since they're sort of like minibosses.  You won't see very many enemies that drop them until around chapter or 8 or 9, when you get to Palumpolum.

Here's where you can start farming in earnest.  Spoilers follow.  Each area is better farming than the last.

When sneaking in to Palumpolum there's several groups of PSICOM/Guardian Corps dudes patrolling that you can farm semi-effectively.  You can go from the save point, to the end of the tunnel, then come back.  Only the earliest ones will have respawned, but you can save and reload to respawn them all.

A little bit later after after Snow meets back up with them, is an area where's there's more larger groups of soldiers.  These also are the first enemies who can drop Incentive Chips which sell for for 2500 and like the Credit Chips are meant to be sold.  There's usually one or two in each group who can drop it and have Credit Chips as their common drop.  Once you get the rhythm of 5 starring the fights (I found Rav/Rav and Rav/Com paradigms, with Med/Sen or Med/Com only when you're really hurting to be the only feasible way) you'll normally get maybe 3-4 credit chips and an incentive chip or two per run.  There's also a couple enemies that can drop Rhodocrosite which is used as a catalyst.  It takes about 5-10 minutes per run, and there's a save point on either end of the area so you can just save and reload.

The next area is at Hope's dad's apartment, where there's two groups of PSICOM guys that endlessly respawn if you walk a short distance away.  The apartment is roughly circular so you can just run down the hallway in one direction until you get tired of farming them.  There's more incentive chip droppers in these groups.  It's also about when there's some nice accessories you may want to buy (I think 2nd tier str and magic stuff) and upgrade.  This place is pretty awesome since it's essentially infinite enemy density.  About 5 seconds between fights.

The last is around the middle of Chapter 10 (I think) where you're on the big airship, and there's a big section of hallway with about 7 groups of 3-5 PSICOM guys that drop both Credit Chips and Incentive Chips.  There's a savepoint as well as a door to another section of deck you can go through to force respawns.  Basically same song and dance as the previous parts.

After that the next (also much more effective) is the chocobo farming which is in linked guide.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so, that really can't happen. You *can* farm gil in the early game, but in comparison to things you really need to buy in the late game, anything you would get is a pittance. Yeah, the Incentive Chips are pretty nice, selling at 2,500, but I've beaten the game and right now am farming Platinum Ignots, Trapezehedrons, and Gold Dusts. These are all collected from the Adamantortoises and Adamancheilds of Gran Pulse (and yes, I beat them legitimately without deathspamming). The Gold Dust sells for 15,000 gil apiece, and the Platinum Ignots 10x that (150,000). The Trapezehedron sells for only 10,000, but is the only component that can make the Ultimate Weapons, and would cost 2,000,000 gil if you were to buy it. To add, there isn't really anything you can do with gil until about chapter 9 or 10. Just wait until then to gil farm, as it is much more efficient and worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** : Spam Vanille's Death spell on Adamantortoises in gran pulse right when you unlock tier 2 Belladonna Wand with sab-syn-sab (vanille-hope-fang for me)

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to get fast gil is after you get to Cacoon, there will be the second form of the head hunter. They drop incentive chips and perfume which sells for 23k and is more common and easier to get then the gold dust. The best point to do this is before you fight the Proudclad; the second time you fight him there are groups of them. It's fast gil and decent CP.

Answer (score 0):

When you have Vanille and Hope first enter the Fal Cie Vestige at the start of the game, you can farm Fortisols from the Panterons. Each Fortisol is worth 500 gil.